# Join and Group by SQL to NSFetchRequest Statements

Tags: ios, core-data

I am using core data first time and facing issue in fetching data from two Tables/Entity.

SQL is as below which is working fine:

```
Select * from ZMESSAGE msg Left Join ZCONTACT c ON c.ZCHANNEL = msg.ZCHANNEL group by msg.ZCHANNEL Order by msg.ZDATE
```

Can you please suggest, How to write in NSFetchRequest Statement?

My Entity as below:
[image]

I have tried some cases and last one is as below:

```
NSFetchRequest* fetchGroupSummary = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Message"];

NSEntityDescription* entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Message" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

NSRelationshipDescription *groupName = [entity.relationshipsByName objectForKey:@"channels"];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"channels.channel == channel"];

[fetchGroupSummary setEntity:entity];
[fetchGroupSummary setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
[fetchGroupSummary setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:groupName, nil]];
[fetchGroupSummary setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObject:groupName]];
[fetchGroupSummary setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[fetchGroupSummary setPredicate:predicate];

NSError* error = nil;
NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchGroupSummary error:&error];

return results;
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you describe what the SQL request is supposed to do?

Comment: Yes, SQL is return list of users with user last message